# Spring не удается получить jdbcTemplate для работы с mysql jdbc

Tags: java, spring

В POM.XML  по мимо прочих подключил следующие зависимости:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

В папке WEB-INF создал файл applicationContext.xml со следующим содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

в контроллере указал свойство:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

При запуске появляется ошибка:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: А сам бин `JdbcTemplate`? Его тоже надо объявить в applicationContext.xml тогда

Comment: То есть нечто `<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
/>`